# Total vs listed directories

Tags: directory, ls

On a server when I type in `ls -al` I get a list of the directories

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Feb 13  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May 11  2011 ..
drwxr-xr-x 55 torg torg 4096 May 15 05:40 stuff
```

However the total tells me that there should be 12 directories present. Why is this? I was under the impression that the `-a` flag revealed all directories. Is there some more effective way of seeing all directories, or is the total referring to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `total` line is the number of blocks for all files referenced in that directory, not the number of directories. The number of directories is given by the link count of `.` (the number 3 before the user): It is one for the link to this directory from its parent plus one for the `.` pointing at itself plus one link for each subdirectory's `..` entry. Your example's 3 is 1 subdirectory, the `stuff`. And in turn, `stuff` has 53 subdirectories.